# Underline ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

The following code is responsible for displaying the characteristics of the device (I shortened code for ease of demonstration, but the essence of my question is visible.). It's very simple.
Tell me how to add the lines that I marked in the photo in red. Exactly this length, and exactly at this distance from the text.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800, maxHeight: 300),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            title: const Text('Brand:', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 25)),
                            trailing: Text('${device.brand} ', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 20 ))),

                          ListTile(
                            title: const Text('Operation system:', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 25)),
                            trailing: Text('${device.operation_system} ', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 20 ))),
                        ],),)))));}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Divider` between `ListTile` widgets.

```dart
ListTile(..),
Divider(color: Colors.red, endIndent: 16, indent: 16), // THIS
ListTile(...)
```

While it gets some spaces even after using  `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero` on `ListTile`, we can use `Transform.translate` on `Divider`.

```dart
Transform.translate(
    offset: Offset(0, -18), //adjust based on your need
    child: Divider(...)
```

If you are using `Container` for divider, you will also get `transfom`

```dart
Container(
  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -16, 0),
   ....
),
```

More about  [Transform.translate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.translate.html). You can also check about [ListView.separated](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html).

Comment: Can I adjust the spacing between line and text? Your variant is good, but there is a large distance between the line and the text. Can it be made smaller?

Comment: You like to have it underline text ?

Comment: Yes, I need it. Text must be underlined

Answer (score 0):

We can also  use `Container`  with a color

```
   Container(height: 1, color: Colors.grey)
```

like

```
 ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: Text('Home'),
 ),
 Container(height: 1, color: Colors.grey), //divider
 ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
        title: Text('Logout'),
 ),
```

The `Divider` is not available in `cupertino.dart`. So even in that we  can use the same Container technique with `ListView.separated`:

```
 ListView.separated(
   itemCount: 100,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return row;
   },
   separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
     return Container(
             height: 1,
             color: Styles.productRowDivider, // Custom style
           );
   },
 );
```